# how to get a element from a two dimensional array in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I want to compare a string variable with $city variables in this array using a for loop.this is the array

```
$return_array[] = array (
        (int) $row['tid'],
        $city
    );
```

is this correct?

```
 for($i=0;$i<count($return_array);$i++){
     if( $return_array[$i][$city]==$another_city ){//mycode}
}
```

is this correct?I got unexpected result so I 'm not sure whether this way can I access the city variables.

Comment: You're missing a closing curly-brace for the for loop, but I suspect that's just got lost in the copy and paste.

Comment: thanks all.explaining unexpected result will take lot of time and space because my code in the if condition is little bit long.I will check answers you gave me.thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not:
`$return_array[$i][$city]`

But:
`$return_array[$i][1]`